# SQL Query to retrieve 2 digit numbers from the below string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL Query to retrieve 2 digit numbers from the below string

String --> 'Partial:[64][95]'

The output should be in the below format.

64,95

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is Partial created? Can we get to the root of the problem and solve it there?  It Partial always a pair of two digit nums? or can it be just a single two digit num with the other empty? Might there be a triple of two digit nums?

Comment: Partial comes from application.It contains error codes in [].There can be multiple error codes

Comment: Then you need a string splitter. What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Then you can find several great options here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Or maybe it is as simple as nested replace like Yogesh posted in their answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` function several times to replace parts of the string.

In the example below I've set a declared variable to your example string:

```
DECLARE @mystring varchar(100) = 'Partial:[64][95]'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@mystring, 'Partial:[', '')
                      , '][', ',')
              , ']', '') AS [answer]
```

Produces output:

```
answer
------
64,95
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `replace()` :

```
select *, replace(replace(replace(Partial, '][', ','), '[', ''), ']', '')
from table t;
```

However, this would reduce your nested replace via [TRANSLATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but available from `SQL Server 2017`.

Comment: It's actually wrong.  It should be `'Partial'` since it is a string, but then 'Partial' is not being replaced with the empty space.

Comment: @Zorkolot. . . Right but, When i answered it is `[64][95]`.

Comment: To clarify- in this select query you replaced from a _column name (or column alias)_ named "Partial".  But you did not replace the string "Partial" in the query.  You only replaced brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result with the below query.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100);
SET @string = 'Partial:[64][95]';
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string) <> 0
      SET @string = STUFF(@string, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @string), 1, '');
DECLARE @splitstring NVARCHAR(20) = @string;
DECLARE @i INT = 3;
WHILE @i < LEN(@splitstring)
      BEGIN
            SELECT @splitstring = STUFF(@splitstring, @i, 0, ',');
            SET @i = @i +3;
      END;
SELECT @splitstring;
```

Thanks everyone for the help.